# Write a negative number in binary (2's complement) without using the positive number

Tags: twos-complement, integer-arithmetic

The usual way to write `-5` in binary is to write `5` and then get its 2's complement (i.e flip all the bits and add 1):

```
 5 = 0b00000101
-5 = 0b11111011
```

Now is there a way to write `-5` in 2's complement without using `5` itself to start with?

i.e when representing positive numbers we simply do `... + (bit_1 * 2^1) + (bit_0 * 2^0)`

Do we have a similar rule for negative numbers in 2's complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In signed two's complement the bit values are exactly the same as for unsigned, *except* the top bit is negated.  So

-1*bit<sub>n-1</sub>*2<sup>n-1</sup> + bit<sub>n-2</sub>*2<sup>n-2</sup> + ... + bit<sub>1</sub>*2<sup>1</sup> + bit<sub>0</sub>*2<sup>0</sup>